# How to resolve mixed content that was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am try to run React/NodeJS app with a nodejs and client setup. I have everything running fine locally with using Docker/docker-compose. But when I deploy it to AWS ECS, I get the following error:

```
apiRequest.js:52 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myAppUrl/auth/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://0.0.0.0:4000/auth/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  client:
    image: docker-registry:dev-test7

api:
  image: docker-registry:dev-test4
  ports:
    - "4000:4000"

nginx:
  image: docker-registry:nginx:dev-test5
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  depends_on:
    - client
    - api
```

Nginx default.conf

```
upstream client {
 server 0.0.0.0:3000;
}
upstream api {
  server 0.0.0.0:5000;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

The app deploys fine to AWS ECS and it runs fine locally with a docker-compose up. I thought since the app was calling the nodejs api's locally, it wouldn't need to use https. I have tried many different variations for the url such as using the domain or IP, but still not working

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "everywhere"; it doesn't make sense to embed it in a URL or in nginx `server` lines.  Something in your code is inserting this URL and that's causing the browser error you show.

Comment: @DavidMaze What should be used instead of the URL? In the config.js I point to a http://localhost:4000 (also tried http://0.0.0.0:4000 and http://domainUrl.com:4000). Should I have something else in there?

Comment: You can generally use other containers' Compose service names as hostnames.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has more details.  ECS has a different setup, and AWS documentation like [Configuring Your Service to Use a Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-create-loadbalancer.html) describes some of the required setup.  In neither case do you make outbound connections to 0.0.0.0 ("everywhere") or `localhost` ("this container").